# SSRS Configured on server. But showing URL does not exist on deployment

Tags: sql-server, iis, ssrs-2012

I have configured SSRS in SQL Server 2012 and can access the URL http://localhost/ReportServer_SQLS2012 in browser.But I cannot see any such sites added in IIS manager

[image: IIS Home]

Im my report server project properties i have added Target server URL as http://localhost/ReportServer_SQLS2012. But on clicking deploy its showing 'specified report server url does not found'. I can see a ReportServer data base has been added in SQL Server Management Studio. Is there any additional configuration required for deploying report server project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SQL Server 2008 onwards, Reporting Services does not require IIS. So for a standard installation, you will not see the site in IIS Manager.

If necessary, you can configure Reporting Services using the Reporting Service Configuration Manager which will be available on the machine where reporting services was installed.

This article provides some useful information http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2008/10/20/say-goodbye-to-iis-say-hello-to-httpsys/

As far as connecting to the ReportingServer to deploy a report, in your Project Properties, the TargetServerURL text box needs to be the URL of the target report server.

When publishing to a report server running in native mode, use the URL of the virtual directory of the report server (for example, http://server/reportserver or https://server/reportserver). This is the virtual directory of the Report Server Web Service, not Report Manager.

You should confirm using the Reporting Service Configuration Manager what the Web Service URL is (not the Report Manager URL).

If you do have the correct URL, then something else to try is in your Project Properties General section set the following options to:

TargetReportPartFolder: [Virtual Directory of Report Manager URL] TargetServerURL: http://localhost/[Virtual Directory of Web Service URL]

Note that the first URL is the Report Manager URL.

I also found a MS webpage which provides details on setting deployment setting which may help  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms155802.aspx